# Mockito - Does verify method reboot number of times?

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mockito

If we have this code:

```
@Test
public void test1(){
  Interface1 i1 = mock(Interface1.class)
  method1(); // This method calls i1.mockedmethod()
  verify(i1, times(1)).mockedmethod();
  method1();
  verify(i1, times(2)).mockedmethod();
}
```

I know that it will pass the first verify, but I'm in doubt with the second one. Does verify method counts all the times that the method has been called or it only counts it since the last verify?

Comment: But does it did that always? Or has it options to make the other thing? That's what I'm not sure about...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

*Once created, mock will remember all interactions. Then you can selectively verify whatever interaction you are interested in*.

It means that your mock counts each time you call the method you want and it does not reset when you call `verify`.

If you want further information about that, read this (
this is where I have found these information):

http://site.mockito.org/mockito/docs/current/org/mockito/Mockito.html

Answer (score 79):

Using [void reset(T... mocks)](https://javadoc.io/static/org.mockito/mockito-core/3.6.28/org/mockito/Mockito.html#reset-T...-) will reset all stubbings on the mocks. If you just need to reset the invocation counts for subsequent verifications, use [void clearInvocations(T... mocks)](https://javadoc.io/static/org.mockito/mockito-core/3.6.28/org/mockito/Mockito.html#clearInvocations-T...-).

Comment: Why do the linked docs for `clearInvocations` say, "Try to avoid this method at all costs. Only clear invocations if you are unable to efficiently test your program"? What are the (possible) side effects?

Comment: @JohnK they are just being dramatic, and force their desired test-design-pattern upon readers (and should instead say "`Each test-method shall only assert once maximum, hence don't use this anti-pattern`").

Comment: You could make the two calls and then call verify with times(2).. That would cover the case where one of the calls call twice and the other none. But that seems a somewhat unusual condition

Answer (score 57):

Note that it is possible to reset the times a method was called with `Mockito.reset(mock)`

Update: as suggested below by t7tran, using `clearInvocations(T... mocks)` will reset only the number of invocations

Answer (score 4):

Mockito will remember, so it counts since the first interaction and will not reset.

Also, be aware that `verify(i1, times(1)).mockedmethod();` is the same as `verify(i1).mockedmethod();`.

More info about mockito [here](http://docs.mockito.googlecode.com/hg/org/mockito/Mockito.html).